# I tried to install Ubuntu 20.04 and the installation failed and now I cannot boot on anything (I have dual-boot with Windows)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb-installation

I tried to install Ubuntu 20.04 using a bootable USB over the old Ubuntu. I formated the partition with the previous version of Ubuntu during installing process and the laptop shuted down installing. Right now I can't boot neither the USB or Windows (I had dual-boot Ubuntu-Windows, both on the same SSD). There are 2 cases: I get the "No bootable device" message, or "file 'boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found.". I tried every tutorial and nothing worked. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating the bootable Ubuntu install media again and see if it will boot to the Ubuntu installer. Then run through the install process (it should find the Windows and Ubuntu partitions), and just overwrite the Ubuntu partition.

It sounds like it might not have completed writing the MBR grub loader if the power was interrupted during install the first time, and the USB install media possibly became corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

`No bootable device found` occurs when your PC can’t find a boot device(one or both in dual boot). This happens for many reasons, but here I believe the BIOS got confused as the installation did not complete.
You can follow this [link](https://www.icare-recovery.com/howto/how-to-fix-computer-no-boot-device-available-error-problem.html) to fix your problem.

The simplest thing you can do, Run Ubuntu directly from either a USB stick or a DVD and recover your data and try installing window again and then Ubuntu.